# JavaScript roundslider plugin default settings

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, plugins

I'm trying to use the [roundslider plugin](http://roundsliderui.com/).

I followed the instructions found [here](http://roundsliderui.com/document.html), to include the dependency files, add the HTML and call the plugin.

I created all of this in the following simple .html file, and opened it using chrome.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.roundslider/1.3/roundslider.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.roundslider/1.3/roundslider.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $("#slider1").roundSlider({
                sliderType: "default",
                value: 40
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="slider1" class="rslider"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Chrome opened the page but showed nothing in the div.  Where did I go wrong?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/soundar24/utqgufx0/) example provided by roundslider.

Comment: `$("#slider1")` is not defined when the script loads. Wrap the script in a `$(function() {})` wrapper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the script is called before the HTML is loaded. As a result, `$("#slider1")` is undefined and the function gets called on nothing.

Either:

1. Move your script to the end of the `<body>` or some place after the `<div>`
2. Wrap the entire JS code in a `$(function() {})` wrapper that waits until page load, like so:

   ```
   $(function() {
       $("#slider1").roundSlider({
           sliderType: "default",
           value: 40
       });
   });
   ```

---

The reason the JSFiddle example works is because the code is wrapped in an `window.load()` function, which waits for the HTML to load. (You can see this setting under the setting JavaScript > Load Type).

Internally, this is their script (you can check the Developer Tools to see this in the JSFiddle):

```
//<![CDATA[
$(window).load(function(){
$("#slider1").roundSlider({
    sliderType: "default",
    value: 40
});

$("#slider2").roundSlider({
    sliderType: "min-range",
    value: 40
});

$("#slider3").roundSlider({
    sliderType: "range",
    value: "10,40"
});
});//]]>
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense thank you for the clarification.

Im guessing that the latter of the two would be a the preferred solution?

Comment: And yes, @kayduh, it is more standard